# How to run JUnit test cases in java files that are outside the project?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I know how to run JUnit test cases in java files inside the project, but I would like to run a test case on a java file that is outside the project, like in the Desktop folder, for example. How can I do that?

Comment: If your plan is to use files outside the project, you are going to get problems with build reproducibility

Comment: This is a really bad idea.

Comment: I know guys, but I really need to execute it that way. It is for a research

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with one of test runners like http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/textui/TestRunner.htm

something like

```
java -cp .:path/to/junit.jar:andotherjars junit.textui.TestRunner package.YourTestCaseClass
```

Its recommended to use some build tool like gradle / maven to accomplish same.